# How to get a tagged version of a hugo theme via blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

Building a new website using the R package **blogdown** and the Hugo academic theme worked a few weeks (?) ago:

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
```

The same command today produces a non-functional webpage, perhaps because of an update to hugo-academic. See discussion:

https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/594

So, I would like to use a previously tagged version of hugo-academic. It seems like things should still work, for example, with version 2.0.1. So, I tried this:

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic/tree/v2.1.0")
```

This runs, but I *think* is produces the same non-functional website as the normal command. That is, I am not actually downloading the v2.1.0 tag of hugo-academic that I want.

Is there a way to do that?

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] blogdown_0.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 bookdown_0.7   tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.19    knitr_1.20    
[6] xfun_0.3
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a totally new website with theme "hugo-academic"? Or you want to preview the website with `blogdown:::serve_site()`?
If the theme is broken and you still have your `blogdown` project created some time ago, you can copy the theme manually. It is in folder "themes" in your project.

Comment: > Do you mean that you want to create a totally new website with theme "hugo-academic"? Yes.

Comment: And you don't have the previous version of "hugo-academic" that worked?

Comment: I do have a previous version that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation `?blogdown::new_site` for the syntax of the `theme` argument instead of guessing. The documentation says you should specify the tag name after `@`, e.g.,

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic@v2.1.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the previous version of the theme that works:

1. make a copy of all the project (the folder) that worked;
2. rename the folder;
3. modify `config.toml` file in the new project;
4. modify other contents as required;
5. create a new website.

Comment: No. But thanks! I am teaching a class and need a solution which works (easily) for each student from their own laptop.

Comment: Related question: what is the recommended approach to updating a previously installed academic theme to the latest version on github?